# How many database calls in this EF query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm taking over someone's code and came across this Entity Framework query and I've never seen it done this way. Isn't there a database query every time the .FirstOrDefault is called? So in this case there would be 4 database queries meaning 5 open/close connections to the database? Just trying to understand if this is an ineffective way of doing this which it seems like it to me.

```
var record = from e in ctx.bio_employee.Where(x => x.emp_id == emp_id)
             select new
             {
                  ta.ta_system
                 ,ta.bio_consent_flag
                 ,e.bio_consentform_rid
             };


if (record.FirstOrDefault() != null) 
{
    vm.TASystem = record.FirstOrDefault().ta_system;
    vm.bio_consent_flag = record.FirstOrDefault().bio_consent_flag == null ? "N" : record.FirstOrDefault().bio_consent_flag.Trim().ToUpper();
    vm.employee_bio_consentform_rid = record.FirstOrDefault().bio_consentform_rid;
}
```

Comment: After some research, I surmise that this would indeed generate 4 queries to the database.

Comment: This is obviously bad practice.
There are several reasons to avoid repeating FirstOrDefault:
1. The method would almost certainly be invoked several times, when a local variable could reduce to 1 time.
2. The database records could change in-between invocations, meaning results can change due to deletion, insertion or even physical reordering (no sorting is specified in the query) and therefore subqsequent instructions could work on different records.
3. Code clarity and maintenance,
btw, FirstOrDefault appears 5 times.
Connection to the DB is preserved during all instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That executes the same query 4 or 5 separate times, although connection pooling will reuse a single connection.  Should be

```
var query = from e in ctx.bio_employee.Where(x => x.emp_id == emp_id)
             select new
             {
                  ta.ta_system
                 ,ta.bio_consent_flag
                 ,e.bio_consentform_rid
             };

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null) 
{
    vm.TASystem = result .ta_system;
    vm.bio_consent_flag = result .bio_consent_flag == null ? "N" : result .bio_consent_flag.Trim().ToUpper();
    vm.employee_bio_consentform_rid = result.bio_consentform_rid;
}
```

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to confirm that it would be multiple trips to the database like I assumed. Your answer is effectively what I'm going to convert it to but just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something that I didn't know about so that I could defend my justification to make the change.

Comment: Looking at the answers I'll rephrase my statement based on the fact that it will reuse the connection which I didn't realize. So it is making 4 or 5 query calls but it's not as big of a performance hit as I thought because it's not opening/closing the connection 4 or 5 times. Still, it's unnecessary calls to the database when it only needs to happen once. I'm sure there is still a performance hit for the multiple queries but it's going to be so minor it would for the most part be unnoticeable. On the other hand, code clarity and maintenance like mentioned above justifies the change alone.

Comment: Yes.  Queries and Collections should be clearly distinguished in code.